# Python AttributeError: class object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, attributeerror

When I try to run the code of a class I'm writing, I get an `AttributeError` and I'm not sure why. The specific error is as follows:

```
    self.marker = self.markers[marker[1:]]
AttributeError: 'TTYFigureData' object has no attribute 'markers'
```

Here is part of the class I'm writing:

```
class TTYFigureData(object):
    """
    data container of TTYFigure
    """
    def __init__(
        self,
        x,                      # x values
        y,                      # y values
        marker          = "_.", # datum marker
        plot_slope      = True
        ):
        self.x          = x
        self.y          = y
        self.plot_slope = plot_slope
        self.set_marker(marker)
        self.markers = {
            "-" : u"None" ,
            "," : u"\u2219"
        }

    def set_marker(
        self,
        marker
        ):
        if marker in [None, "None", u"None", ""]:
            self.plot_slope = True
            self.marker = ""
        elif marker[0] == "_":
            self.marker = self.markers[marker[1:]]
        else:
            self.marker = marker
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your code style is somewhat... idiosyncratic (*"awful"* seemed a bit pejorative), which makes it hard to follow. Note, though, that you call `self.set_marker` **before** initialising `self.markers`. Given that `self.markers` appears to be fixed, why not make it a class attribute?

Comment: Please do post a *full traceback* for Python errors. For this case, for example, the fact that `set_marker()` is called from `__init__` is a crucial clue as to what is going wrong, the traceback would show that.

Comment: @jonsharpe Ah, that's it! Well spotted. Thanks for looking.

The code is rough and I know the approach of having a new line for each function argument is not considered standard. Is the approach really so bad, particularly for large numbers of arguments?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for that tip. You're quite right.

Comment: @d3pd: yes, it made it very hard to distinguish between argument list and method body, for example. Please do read the [Python styleguide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which offers better alternatives.

Comment: Not just that, also the aligned whitespace around default values/assignments - worse than non-compliant, that's actually **inconsistent**. If you want to document the parameters (which is a good thing!), consider doing so in [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) - IDEs and automatic documentation generators can then actually *use* the information, which they generally can't with inline comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32823936/3001761) explains the problem and gives the minimal solution. However, given that `self.markers` appears to be constant, I would make it a *class attribute* rather than recreating it for every instance:

```
class TTYFigureData(object):
    """Data container of TTYFigure."""

    MARKERS = {
        "-": u"None" ,
        ",": u"\u2219",
    }

    def __init__(self, x, y, marker='_.', plot_slope=True):
        """Document parameters here as required."""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.plot_slope = plot_slope
        self.set_marker(marker)

    def set_marker(self, marker):
        """See also here - usage guidance is also good."""
        if marker in [None, "None", u"None", ""]:
            self.plot_slope = True
            self.marker = ""
        elif marker[0] == "_":
            self.marker = self.MARKERS[marker[1:]]
        else:
            self.marker = marker
```

*(note also changes to style in line with [the official guidance](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/))*

Comment: Thank you for your clear solution and for your guidance on changing the markers attribute from an instance attribute to a class attribute.

Answer (score 5):

In your `__init__` method, you call `self.set_marker()` **before** you set `self.markers`:

```
self.set_marker(marker)
self.markers = {
    "-" : u"None" ,
    "," : u"\u2219"
}
```

So when `set_marker()` runs, there is no `self.markers` **yet**. Move the call down a line:

```
self.markers = {
    "-" : u"None" ,
    "," : u"\u2219"
}
self.set_marker(marker)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear solution. It was a silly thing to miss.